# Символ '#' программно не заходит в в поле ввода номера телефона

Tags: java, android

Пытаюсь передать телефон в поле ввода и не пропускает знак решетки.

```
strBuild.append("tel:").append(mPrefix).append(tmp.getPhone()).append("\u0023");
Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL);
callIntent.setData(Uri.parse(strBuild.toString()));
```

URI строиться четко, в логах все правильно, но после перехода в конце нет знака решетки.

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Ответ](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4816002) с большого SO:

Т.к. `#` является спецсимволом для URI, его надо экранировать:

```
Intent out = new Intent();
out.setAction(Intent.ACTION_DIAL);
out.setData(Uri.parse("tel:" + Uri.encode("+12345#123")));
startActivity(out);
```

Или напрямую вписывать `%23`.

[Либо](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11981581) использовать `Uri.fromParts`:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL);
intent.setData(Uri.fromParts("tel", "#123456#", "#")); 
startActivity(intent);
```